# Example: Drop a column name in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have downloaded the Wisconsin breast cancer dataset from the UCI Machine Learning Repository and modified wdbc_data a little bit such that its first row contains the variable names and it is saved as a csv file with semicolons as separators.

I can import this file and print its head:

```
df = pd.read_csv("inputs/breastCancer.csv")
print(df.head())
```

which results in the following output in PyCharm:

```
id;diagnosis;radius_mean;texture_mean;perimeter_mean;area_mean;smoothness_mean;compactness_mean;concavity_mean;concave_points_mean;symmetry_mean;fractal_dimension_mean;radius_se;texture_se;perimeter_se;area_se;smoothness_se;compactness-se;concavity_se;concave_points_se;symmetry_se;fractal_dimension_se;radius_worst;texture_worst;perimeter_worst;area_worst;smoothness_worst;compactness_worst;concavity_worst;concave_points_worst;symmetry_worst;fractal_dimension_worst
0  842302;M;1799;1038;1228;1001;1184;2776;3001;14...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
1  842517;M;2057;1777;1329;1326;8474;7864;869;701...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
2  84300903;M;1969;2125;130;1203;1096;1599;1974;1...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
3  84348301;M;1142;2038;7758;3861;1425;2839;2414;...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
4  84358402;M;2029;1434;1351;1297;1003;1328;198;1...
```

That's what I was expecting. Now I want to drop the first two columns, starting with id:

```
df = df.drop(columns=['id'], axis=1)
print(df.head())
```

and here I obtain the following error:

```
KeyError: "['id'] not found in axis"
```

I know this question has been asked before in several variations, but usually the answer says: Modify axis. Well, my axis parameter is set. And I have double checked that there is no additional space character in my column, there really is only 'id'. Why is this column name not found? Can anyone explain?

Comment: guess you need `;` as sep while reading csv `pd.read_csv("inputs/breastCancer.csv",sep=';')`

Comment: OMG, thx so much Anurag! I figured ';' was the default separator.

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you're trying to read the CSV file, is taking the ID Column as your index, so it's better if you do:

```
df.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

In that way, I think it'll not take the ID as the index. In case that doesn't work, try this:

```
df.reset_index(drop = True).head()
```

Here's a cool [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/pandas-index-explained-b131beaf6f7b) about indexes in pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Problem: csv file converted to dataframe using pd.read_csv does not recognise id in axis = 1.

logic: 'Drop' can be used only on DataFrame

Corrected code below:

```
data = `pd.DataFrame(filename) 
filename.drop(['id'], axis = 1)`
```